# Prevent dynamically added textboxes from disappearing on page refresh

Tags: javascript, php

I have a field where textboxes are added dynamically using jQuery. 
The problem is I have other fields on that page which is mandatory to fill, so if a user forgets to fill a mandatory field the page refreshes and the dynamically added textboxes disappears, how should I prevent this to happen?

Would appreciate if someone could help me out, thanks.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#insert-line-button').on("click", function(){
            var noOfRows = 1;
            for(var i = 0; i < noOfRows; i++){
                $('#myTable').append("<tr style='height: 5rem;'><td><input type='text' name='input[]' " +
                    "class='form-control'/></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type='button' value='x' " +
                    "id='deleteRowButton' class='btn btn-danger'/></td></tr>")
            }

        });

        $("#myTable").on('click', 'input[id="deleteRowButton"]', function(event) {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Either do clientside validation (so the page isn't refreshed in order to do the validation) (do not replace serverside to clientside validation), or set a cookie with the fields and their value

Comment: One way is you can ask a confirmation before reloading the page and another way is you can set a cookie variable for dynamic fields.

Comment: @Qirel thanks for suggesting, I ended up adding clientside validation.